# Publish a collection multiple times Meteor js

Tags: pagination, meteor-blaze, meteor-publications, meteor-collections

I have a collection that I have to publish as a whole as well in part. The challenge now is that once I publish as a whole it overrides the one that is suppose to return only 5 at a time. The publishing with a set limit is to achieve pagination while publishing all goes into a dropdown box. How do I publish a collection so that none will override another?

This is publishing in part. Set with a limit of 5.

```
Meteor.publish('userSchools', function (skipCount) {
  check(skipCount, Number);
  user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:this.userId})
  if(user) {
      if(user.emails[0].verified) {
         return SchoolDb.find({userId: Meteor.userId()}, {limit: 5, skip: skipCount});
      } else {
         throw new Meteor.Error('Not authorized');
         return false;
      }
   }
});
```

Published as a whole

```
Meteor.publish('allvalues', function () {
  user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:this.userId})
  if(user) {
      if(user.emails[0].verified) {
         return SchoolDb.find({userId: Meteor.userId()});
      } else {
         throw new Meteor.Error('Not authorized');
         return false;
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This how Meteor pub-sub behaves. What you can do is put `limit` and `skipcount` in Subscribed collection as well inside template where you subscribe in parts.